# Noun meaning "location of incident" or "location of attack"

Tags: word-request, nouns

Is there a noun that means or is synonymous with "location of incident" or "location of attack"? Preferably a countable noun, for talking about multiple of these locations. For example:

> You need to gather evidence from (these locations).

Comment: Could you add a sentence the noun should fit into? More context would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either **the scene of the crime** or just **the crime scene**.

Answer (score 0):

'Ground zero' would fit for an incident, but not for a military attack.

Comment: Thank you, but I was thinking something countable, for use when talking about multiple of these locations. Edited question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

attack locations

incident locations

attack and incident can function as adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "the sites", depending on your context.  It would be implied that the sites are relevant to the data collection or other act that you are performing.  "Sites" is useful both for general outdoor locations as well as specific indoor locations, again depending on context.